# 16 gb RAM specs for mid 2012 macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I have a mid 2012 Macbook pro.

I want to upgrade it to 16 GB -- I know Apple does not support this but is possible.

I would appreciate it if someone can give me the specs of the RAM to order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple answer: PC3-12800 , or to be more specific, a DDR3-1600MHz 204 PIN SODIMM.

DMS Sells a [16GB kit](http://www.datamemorysystems.com/dm50-234-1-x-2/), as does [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/macbook-pro-2*7ghz-intel-core-i7-%2815-inch-ddr3%29-mid-2012/CT3327434) and [OWC](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/1600DDR3S16P/).